# Is it a bad practice to modify SQLAlchemy models for other usage after expunging?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have the following SQLAlchemy model.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import String, Integer

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
  __table__ = "users"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  first_name = Column(String)
  last_name = Column(String)
  age = Column(Integer)

  def as_dict(self):
      return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys()}
```

And I make a query to my database like so:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from user import User


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Add something to database
user = User(first_name="John", last_name="Doe", age=38)
session.add(user)
session.commit()

# query for the result now
result = session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
session.expunge_all()
```

Now my question is, is it a bad practice to modify `result` after it has been expunged from the session if I just want to serialize and send it back to the client?

e.g.

```py
# ..continuing from above
result.age = result.age + 4

print(json.dumps(result.as_dict()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practise if you have a legitimate reason for doing so, although it may be confusing if the data returned from your application differs from the data in your database.

Consider your example of a user with a `first_name` and `last_name`, it's perfectly legitimate to combine those and return it as `name`. Your business case may allow users to customise how they wish to be identified and greeted, some preferring first name whilst some users may prefer first and last. In this case it's good practise to perform this logic otherwise it would become the responsibility of the client application which may have to be repeated in several places.

Comment: My only concern here is that I'm directly manipulating the ORM model which sort of feels like I'm trying to write it in the database when it clearly isn't the intent here. I'm okay with this approach as long as it's generally accepted in the wider community but if there are better ways to do so w/o actually creating a new plain `User` object then I'm curious to hear them as well.